# How do you clear the Lua console workspace?

Tags: lua, workspace

I'm basically looking for an equivalent of [Matlab's `clear` command](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html). Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "console workspace"? Are you talking about what happens when you run the `lua.exe` executable without an input file?

Comment: Exactly; the REPL.

Comment: Lua does not have workspaces.  You can clear global object (to release its memory) by `var = nil`.

Comment: The closest command is `os.exit()`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Lua's "console workspace" interacts with the console in the only ways that the C standard library can do so. It can read from stdin. It can write to stdout and stderr. But that's it.

Clearing a console requires functionality beyond that, and the Lua interpreter simply doesn't have access to that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Lua does not support this functionality. However the iPython Notebook (which supports Lua) has an option to restart the interpreter (Kernel->Restart).